# Como por um field em um objeto em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como por um field em um objeto em javascript?

```
var test = {}
undefined
test = 1
1
test.example = 10
10
test.example
undefined
console.log(test.example)
undefined
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que voce pretente fazer? Em qual pagina você quer criar um field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript é uma linguagem dinâmica, de tipagem fraca. Uma das suas características é que variáveis podem guardar qualquer tipo de valor, e podem trocar de tipo sem que isso gere nenhum erro ou aviso.

Com isso em mente, veja o que você fez:

```js
// Declara uma variável e guarda um objeto nela
var test = {};
console.log( typeof test ); // "object"
// Troca o valor da variável por um número
test = 1;
console.log( typeof test ); // "number"
```

A partir do momento em que `test` contém um número, já não adianta mais tentar atribuir propriedades, já que números são tipos primitivos, e não objetos (até existem objetos *wrappers* para números, mas não vou entrar em detalhes já que você não os utiliza no código da pergunta).

Respondendo à pergunta do título: uma vez tendo um objeto, basta atribuir uma nova propriedade:

```js
var test = {};
test.example = 10;
console.log( test.example ); // 10
```

Comment: Obrigado! Imaginei algo parecido, mas demorei a aceitar esse comportamento, acreditava que o primitivo não aceitaria a propertie e levantaria uma exceção.

Comment: Na verdade, quando você tenta atribuir uma propriedade a um primitivo, ele embala esse primitivo num objeto, mas descarta esse objeto no final do *statement*. Esse mecanismo é que faz funcionar coisas como `(10).toString(); // "10"`.